# #VALUE! align cell position missing (excel)

Tags: excel, vba

I use this formula to align cells like here

[image]

I put this formula in **E3** and then I press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

```
=INDEX($D$3:$D$6,MATCH("*" & MID(B3,SEARCH("http",B3),99),$D$3:$D$6,0))
```

The formula stops at the first step, but does not consider that the function that values do not align correctly, that is what I seek. 
if I change position of cells of column D formula return me this error:

```
#VALUE!
```

Look this pic, please:

[image]

Is there any solution to correct position of cells of **column E** with column D **after** first formula alignment between B-D?

**Note**: alignment must following same LINK and It should value the same function as a loop. Loop because function must look at the alignment with the neighboring column, in our case is the D until e.g `http://beta.com` link is on the same row level. They could take more steps, but eventually you have to get to an array. P.S: each link of start column (B) is unique

Comment: the column E formula checks current string in B and picks the one in D which does match and shows it. This way it will be aligned by column B (which is obvious and makes sense). how to know that "beta" needs to be in row 5 instead of row 4?

Comment: mmm..I do not know, I was wondering what solution could be adopted

Comment: if you can not give a reason for that, how to code it? also, the `#VALUE` is due to the fact that column B is empty at row 6... there is nothing to find ^^;

Comment: I know this Dirk, but I try to find a script solution that fix this `#VALUE` problem correcting position of strings in column E. Formula it is not enough. Have you got any idea? I'm not a programmer so..my ideas end here..sorry. I try to find a simple solution with excel, but I see that it is not possible. What do you think?

Comment: and again... how to know WHERE the text needs to be? the is no code which looks at your sheet and pushes the data around like you think it will look better... you need strict reasons for each action

Comment: alignment must following same `LINK` and It should value the same function as a loop. Loop because function must look at the alignment with the neighboring column, in our case is the D until `http://beta.com` link is on the same row level. They could take more steps, but eventually you have to get to an array. P.S: each link of start column (B) is unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put in E3:

```
=IF(D3<>"",INDEX(D:D,MATCH("*"&MID(INDEX($B$3:$B$6,COUNTIF($D$3:$D3,"<>")),SEARCH("http://",INDEX($B$3:$B$6,COUNTIF($D$3:$D3,"<>"))),999),D:D,0)),"")
```

and copy down. this is NOT an array formula.

**EDIT**

If I got you right, then all you want is to flip over the original formula...

```
=IF(D3="","",INDEX(B:B,MATCH("*" & MID(D3,SEARCH("http://",D3),999),B:B,0)))
```

Comment: you are very near to solution, but your formula reorder position only. Is possible to replace on column E prefix of column D with prefixes of column B? e.g `<title>http://alfa.com` where `<title>` is prefix of column D but in column E I want see `jackhttp://alfa.com` Alignment is perfect but not prefixes before `http://` If you want I can close this answer and open new with a new question

Comment: So you want the values from column B matched to the vales of column D... simply the opposite of your original formula

Comment: something you missing in your `EDIT` formula. It return me `#VALUE!` like strings but position is correct.

Comment: you are a master. Answer Solved, Thanks. Nice to meet you.